# How to Show particular Paragraph in RichTextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, richtextbox, rtf

I have multiple paragraphs in my RichTextBox. Is it possible to show particular paragraph only alone?

thanks in Advance...

Comment: pls answer.. i am new to this field.. just help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep paragraph's starting and ending indexes. So you can make selection and navigate to there using `RichTextBox.SelectionStart` and then `RichTextBox.SelectionLength`. There is no such built in method. You will have to do it all yourself.